# Enable/disable responsiveness

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a template with Bootstrap 3 and I want to implement an option to enable/disable responsiveness. This is much harder to do now because Bootstrap 3 is now 'mobile first'.

The problem I'm facing is that when I want the responsiveness to be disabled I have to change all grid col-* classes to col-xs .

Is there a way to make all the grid classes behave like col-xs only when I want?

Comment: What do you mean by "disable responsiveness"? Do you just [want smartphones to display the full desktop website](http://leavesofcode.net/2013/07/08/responsive-design-with-switch-to-desktop-site-option/), or do you want desktop browsers to see the smartphone design?

Comment: @Blazemonger I want the smartphones or tablets to display the full desktop website, but when using bootstrap 3 only removing the meta viewport is not enough [link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive). Eg. for my desktop website I use col-lg-6 and col-lg-offset-4, but on smartphones I'm forced to use col-xs-6 and there is no way I could offset because there are no xs classes for offset, push or pull